# Elm Recursive Mapping?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, signals, elm

I'm trying to write a game of life clone in Elm and I've got some difficulty with how to draw an updating board.

I represent the cells on the board as `(List (List Int))` in a variable called `gameBoardList`

I use this function to update the board

```
transformBoardList : List (List Int) -> List (List Int)
transformBoardList l = nextVertRow l 0
```

I'm able to turn the `gameBoardList` into a form and draw it as an element, and even apply the `transformBoardList` function to that without an issue.

What I don't understand is how I can have my board updating constantly. I've checked out the past dependent mapping but it looks to me like I need some sort of recursive mapping so I can keep applying `transformBoardList` every update

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have some game state, and an update function, you can use those and `foldp` and a time ticker to get a regularly updating game.

```
startState = gameBoardList -- for example
update = transformBoardList -- for example
view = .. -- you said you had this too

input = Time.every second -- a time ticker
state = Signal.foldp (\_ s -> update s) startState input
main = view <~ state
```